# How to render volumetric light on a transparent image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I have principled shader plugged into my world output and a spotlight in my scene, as well asthe film settings transpareny turned on and it keeps rending out the black background?

I have provided a screenshot and rendered image[image].[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=vDLXqJz9" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vDLXqJz9/)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it looks like a limitation in Cycles, I hope someone will confirm, but for example it works fine with Eevee, so the solution may be to use a cube instead and give it the Principled Volume

Comment: yeah ive tried evreything, appriciate the shot